# Alerta em input caso dado digitado seja inválido

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suponha que há um input que receba um número de telefone. Caso a máscara retorne que ele seja inválido, como inserir um aviso (html e css) no *input* para dizer ao usuário que o dado é inválido? Não tenho muita noção de interação o JS, apenas consegui dar a mensagem através do `alert`, mas convenhamos que é meio chato.

OBS: Quero uma solução sem o uso de jQuery.

Comment: Tem várias formas de fazer, depende do que é "alerta" pra você.

Comment: Qualquer coisa ao redor do input. Seja mudar a borda dele, inserir uma div ao lado do formulario, coisas assim, direto no html

Answer (score 5):

Pode usar [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) para validar um campo (texto, número, email, etc...) e por meio dessa regra, decidir se deve exibir/esconder o alerta para o usuário:

```css
.input span {
  color: red;
  display: none /* Esconde o span */
}

.input input:invalid + span {
  display: inline /* Exibe o span somente se o input for inválido. */
}
```

```html
<div class='input'>
  <input type='email' placeholder='me@email.com'>
  <span>email inválido.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma é usando o atributo [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) do HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <label for="choose">Qual seu telefone?</label>
  <input id="choose" name="i_like" pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}" required>
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Nesse exemplo, o pattern é para telefone, em formato *99-99999-9999*.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/d414erhL/